# Unable to change View's background when it is disabled

Tags: android, android-styles

in styles.xml

```
<style name="waitnessCallEnableStyle">
    <item name="backgroundColor">@color/waitness_color</item>
</style>
```

in **res/colors/waitness_color.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/circle_paint_dark" android:state_enabled="false" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/circle_transparent" />
</selector>
```

in my xml layout:

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/waitressCallViewCircle"
    style="@style/waitnessCallEnableStyle"
    android:layout_width="144dp"
    android:layout_height="144dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

In the activity when I disable the `view`

```
private lateinit var dataBinding: MainActivityBinding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    dataBinding =
            DataBindingUtil.setContentView<MainActivityBinding>(this, R.layout.main_activity)
    dataBinding.setHandler(this)

}

private fun setWaitressCallMakeMode() {
    dataBinding.waitressCallContainer.isClickable = false
    dataBinding.waitressCallContainer.isEnabled = false
    dataBinding.executePendingBindings()
}
```

it does not work. `Background` color does not change when `view` is disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you are trying to set `Drawable` as background color in `View`, which is not correct. try as `background`.

use

```
<item name="android:background">@color/waitness_color</item>
```

instead of

```
<item name="backgroundColor">@color/waitness_color</item>
```

And since it's a background, it is quite logical to move this selector from **res/color/** to **res/drawable/**. Also don't forgot to rename the selector as `waitness_background` to align with characteristics. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

create a color selector.

```
  <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


      <item android:state_enabled="true" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_button_gradient"/>
   <item android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="@color/gray"/>

    </selector>
```

in a style:

```
<style name="YourStyle">
     <item name="android:background">@color/your_color</item>
     <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
</style>
```